# Do you go to your bed (if any) on re-spawn or are you completely relocated?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you re-spawn after accidentally crash landing into lava, do you re-spawn to your bed that you made or to the location where you originally started off?

Comment: If you place a block above the spawning block you will spawn in the upper block not in the original spawn

Answer (score 8):

If you slept in a bed before you died, the bed still exists, and there is enough space on it for you to respawn, you will respawn there. Otherwise you will respawn at your initial spawn point.  Dying from lava doesn't change this.

Comment: careful about where you have beds though, i have suffocated after respawning because there wasnt enough space around my bed.

Comment: What about if you've slept in the bed, but then picked it up again to carry it with you and replaced it elsewhere. Do you still respawn in that bed even though it's not in the same place as when you were last in it? (Thinking of going exploring carrying a bed with me so I'm not sure if repeatedly mining and replacing the bed will cause any respanwing issues).

Comment: @JonW If you pick up a bed and put it down again, it becomes a different bed. You'll need to sleep in it again to change your spawn to it.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

When you die, you have three options of respawn:

1. You got bed placed in somewhere, with enough space (1 block : BlockBedBlock)
   and you have sleep, and you don't removed it before die --> Respawn in Bed
2. You got bed placed in somewhere, with enough space (1 block : BlockBedBlock)
   and you have sleep, but you have removed it before die and placed again wihtout sleep -   -> Respawn in "original point of respawn"
3. You don't have bed --> you respawn in the "original point of respawn"

Answer (score 1):

Yes,as long as you have slept in it. If you haven't slept in the bed then you will be at your original spawn.

Answer (score 1):

You can only respawn in your bed if you have Slept in the bed and if there is at least 3 blocks of space between your bed and cealing/ roof but it's better to have more space between the two just to be sure you'll spawn back in your house/ on your bed.

Answer (score -2):

If you do not have a bed, you can spawn anywhere. If you do, you respawn at bed location.

Comment: This is incorrect. No bed means you spawn at the initial spawn point.